# Cannot insert input text to url in fetch api

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am trying to insert the value of my stateful variable (myValue) to the api url after q=
I tried using ${} but it is not working.
It is working when I insert text righ in to url, but I need to insert the input variable. ( sorry for messy code, I am a beginner )

p.s ignore the api key, I just replace it with *** here.

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";

import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = createRef();
    this.state = {
      myValue: "",
      temp : "" 
    };
  }
  showRefContent = () => {
    this.setState({
      myValue: this.textInput.current.value
    });
   
    const uriEncodedCity = encodeURIComponent(this.state.myValue);
   
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=madrid&appid=***')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
      temp : data.main.temp 
    }),
    console.log(this.state.temp)
    );
      
  }
   handleChange = (e) =>
    this.setState({
      myValue: e.target.value
    });

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
         <div >
        <TextField  inputRef={this.textInput}
        id="demo-helper-text-misaligned-no-helper" label="City name"
         />
         <br></br>
        <Button margin = "right:20" size="large" variant ="contained" onClick={this.showRefContent}>Get Weather</Button>
        </div>
        <p>
          {this.state.myValue.length > 0
            ? <WeatherCard temp = {this.state.temp} />
            : "no text"}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `` or '' with ${}. Make sure you use ``.

```
fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${}&appid=***`)
```

Comment: First I used ' '  but now I changed it to ``  and it is higlighting my variable now, however it still doesn't work giving an error :  Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')

Comment: You haven't added the handleChange function to TextField? onChange={handleChange}

Comment: I have a conditional rendering componenet ( <WeatherData/> ) which is based on input value. If I insesrt the handleChange to the text field, it triggers WeatherData to render so I just removed it

Comment: I actually had to delete that function on the post, cos its not used. I forgot. Sorry for confusing you with it

Comment: how does the TextField update the myValue state without on onChange function then?

Comment: Oh I see, on the onClick. It's probably cause you are using the state variable in the URL? Since you are updating the state and calling fetch within the same function, myValue won't have updated its' state yet, so it'd be blank.  Pass this.textInput.current.value into the url instead

Comment: Working! Thank you!